# Appium::TouchAction.new.tap doesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, ruby, appium

```
And(/^I click OK button in popup$/) do
  #Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x:0.64, y:0.57, count: 1).perform
  Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x: 270, y: 506,count: 1).perform
end

And(/^I click Allow button in popup$/) do
  #Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x:0.64, y:0.57, count: 1).perform
  Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x: 270, y: 506,count: 1).perform 
end
```

Given the next code, I work with Appium 1.9.1, Ruby 2.3.7 and Cucumber to automate iOS app, if I'm passing relative coordinates (percentage) - then appium doesn't perform any taps, but, if I comment out lines with absolute coordinates and comment lines with relative coordinates - all taps will work. The strangest thing is that if I use relative coordinates in 1st line and absolute coordinates in second line - it will perform first tap, but won't perform second.
My goal is to use relative coordinates everywhere, so tests will be usable on devices with any screen resolution, please advice, if there are any known solutions to use relative coordinates (or if I'm doing smth wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through your code snippet, I assume you are dealing with alert pop-up in iOS device.

In iOS, with Appium Java client, I can deal with pop-up using traditional `driver.switchTo().alert();`.

> Here `driver` refers to `IOSDriver`.

I'm sure there must be equivalent to this in Ruby as well.

Try using Alert class to accept the alerts instead of tapping on the coordinates.

Comment: Thanks a lot!That helped